# How to run multiple node.js scripts from different IP?

Tags: node.js, debian

I have one Debian server that has 2 different IP address. 
How to run two copies of my NodeJS script from different IP address?

Comment: Do you mean like `server.listen(IP1);` on server1 and `server.listen(IP2);` on server2?

Comment: No, I want to make requests to another web address from 2 different IP. server.listen() didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

**http.request()** and **request()** has **localAddress** option. Set it to IP what you need and use.